# whether metamask can be used on cell phone browser

Tags: metamask

whether metamask can be used on cell phone browser? any plugin for cell phone? thanks
I try to use a wallet to send eth easily, but metamask can only work for desktop etc. for mobile, any metamask solution?

Comment: You can use it with Firefox, at least with Android, if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 5):

A beta version of metamask for mobile has been released recently. You can try it from [here](https://mobile.metamask.io)

Answer (score 3):

MetaMask can't be used on your phone, but there are dApp browsers in different apps that can do the same thing as MetaMask. Personally, I use an app called [Toshi](https://www.toshi.org/), and have had a good experience with it so far. Other options include: [Trust Wallet](https://trustwalletapp.com/), [Status.im](https://status.im/), [Cipher](https://www.cipherbrowser.com/).

Comment: A beta version of metamask for mobile has been released recently. You can try it from here: https://mobile.metamask.io/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way you can use metamask on android through firefox...

https://www.cryptokosh.com/tutorial-use-metamask-wallet-on-android-ios/

But you can't use this trick on iOS right now, because iOS has [blocked the extension support on mobile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-ons-firefox-ios).

Or you can use Other browsers like [Cipher](https://www.cipherbrowser.com/), etc.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Metamask addon for firefox on Android O]

Chrome for android still doesn't support extensions. But firefox for android seems to work well.