# Alternatives to Metamask

Tags: web3js, contract-development, wallets, dapps, accounts

What are existing alternatives to metamask with that works online inside existing browsers, that don't require installing a browser extension? What are some of the tradeoffs between them?

Comment: it's nice if you can accept an answer or provide your own answer and accept it. I just check your profile you hardly accept an answer or provide a correct one. You're not contributing to the community but just using it which is not really encouraging

Answer (score 4):

I like frame, have a look at [frame.sh](https://frame.sh/).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you need exactly. [Uport](https://www.uport.me/) will be a good alternative if you want to work in mobile browsers as well. But users need to have there mobiles with them to use the dApp.

if only to use in PC browsers I recommend Metamask. But with mobile browsers metamask is still in early stage. Check [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/56809/16301).

This [list](https://defiprime.com/assets-managament-tools) might help you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Something that may be of interest is https://squarelink.com/

Other than that, metamask is ahead of everyone else as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

The following Ethereum web wallets are now seeing increasing use alongside Metamask for various dapps, none of which require installing a chrome extension.

- [Portis](https://developers.portis.io/)
- [Fortmatic](https://fortmatic.com/)
- [Torus](http://tor.us)
- [Democracy](http://democracy.js.org) <-- the last one is my project

For a comparison of why you might use one wallet over another, and general design considerations that go into making a web wallet, I've written a longer gist which I welcome feedback on.
https://gist.github.com/cryptogoth/c9367f924984fb1f5988d2e76422e060

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to [BlockWallet](https://blockwallet.io/). We are a privacy and security-focused alternative to Metamask and been in development for over two years. With us, you own your keys, but you also own your data - we obfuscate metadata from the node providers and also don't collect anything ourselves. The wallet is packed with cool features like in-wallet bridges, MEV protection, anti-phishing protection, etc etc.